# Getting null for getDescribe()

Tags: apex

```
modulename = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('modulename');
sobj =SObjectFactory.getSObject(modulename);
fieldMap =sobj.getsObjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap();
```

Getting error when try to get the value from below LOC

```
Schema.SObjectField sfield= fieldMap.get('fkcategory__r.name');
```

Comment: You're trying to get a related object's field. In order to do that you'll need to perform another describe on the parent object to which `fkcategory__c` looks up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get a field from a parent object through a describe on the child object. You could get the lookup field `__c` but not fields from the parent object `__r.Field__c`. In order to do that you'll need another describe on the parent object (I guess it's `FKCategory__c` in this case) and then get the `Name` field.